# Jquery - slideDown with existing height

Tags: jquery, toggle, slidetoggle

If i have a div with a class that sets the height 100px, and overflow:hidden (effectively a preview of it's contents), how can i incorporate the 'slideDown()' method to slide to the full height of the div? (i.e. remove the height  restriction in the css class).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found answer here: http://sim.plified.com/2008/09/15/sliding-content-from-a-partial-height-with-jquery/

Comment: If you don't want the jumping upon load, you can clone the element, insert it into the DOM offscreen and read the height of the clone.